# Is there a way to return more than 1 row in select without using existing tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Simple question, just out of curiosity.

For example `select 1,2,3` that will show `table` with `one column` and `three rows`.

Something like this: `select values(1),(2),(3)`

***with one select statement**

Comment: Or you can use unpivot, but you still need to select from actual data since producing an imaginary subset would require two selects, by your comment below. Anyway, what's the point here?

Comment: The point that for example we can cross join set of values and it will be the same as cross joining table with one column with multiple rows, so it is interesting what(as it appears) there is no simple index that looks like this
select values(1), (2), (3) 
As I said just out of curiosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it appears there is a simple code that I've been searching for:
`select n from (values (1),(2),(3)) D(c);`

Answer (score 5):

An example for my comment in your post.

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (ONE INT, TWO INT, THREE INT)

INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES (1,2,3)

SELECT UP.COL, UP.VALUE
FROM @TABLE
UNPIVOT (VALUE FOR COL IN (ONE,TWO,THREE)) UP
```

Answer (score 5):

**Query:**

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (i1 INT, i2 INT, i3 INT)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES (1, 2, 3)

SELECT t.*
FROM @t
CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES(i1), (i2), (i3)
) t(value)
```

**Output:**

```
value
-----------
1
2
3
```

**Additional info:**

http://blog.devart.com/is-unpivot-the-best-way-for-converting-columns-into-rows.html